# Combinatorics question about intersecting set systems

Tags: combinatorics

> Prove that every intersecting set system $F \subset P(n)$ is contained in an
>   intersecting set system of size $2^{n−1}$.

I have that $F$ must be of size at most $2^{n-1}$. Not sure how to proceed.